# how to compare contents and mode for 2 linux folders?

Tags: linux

Given 2 folders in centos : /folder1 and /folder2 and each folder has some files and subfolders inside.
I use beyond compare 3 to compare the contents but don't know how to compare the file mode and owner at the same time .

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Generally file attributes are gotten at with `stat`. What language are you programming in?

Comment: Use a `diff dir1 dir2` to compare contents (files and folders and contents).

Comment: i am using php. diff dir1 dir2 can only compare conternt, cannot compare file mode and owner.

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on  http://superuser.com or another StackExchange site. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it didn't have to be done all at once, you could first `diff <(cd /folder1; ls -lR) <(cd /folder2; ls -lR) | grep '^[<>]'` to get owner/mode differences, and then `diff -r /folder1 /folder2` to get content differences.

If you really want it to be done all at once, you could generate a list for each directory that includes name, owner, mode, and checksum, and compare the two. This will only tell you **which** files are different, not what the changes in them are, though.

```
diff \
    <(find /folder1 -printf '%P\t%u:%g\t%M' \( \
        -type b -exec stat -c '\tb:%t:%T\n' -- '{}' \; -o \
        -type c -exec stat -c '\tc:%t:%T\n' -- '{}' \; -o \
        -type d -printf '/\n' -o \
        -type p -printf '|\n' -o \
        -type f -printf '\t' -exec sum -- '{}' \; -o \
        -type l -printf '\t-> %l\n' -o \
        -type s -printf '=\n' -o \
        -printf '\t???\n' \) | sort) \
    <(find /folder2 -printf '%P\t%u:%g\t%M' \( \
        -type b -exec stat -c '\tb:%t:%T\n' -- '{}' \; -o \
        -type c -exec stat -c '\tc:%t:%T\n' -- '{}' \; -o \
        -type d -printf '/\n' -o \
        -type p -printf '|\n' -o \
        -type f -printf '\t' -exec sum -- '{}' \; -o \
        -type l -printf '\t-> %l\n' -o \
        -type s -printf '=\n' -o \
        -printf '\t???\n' \) | sort) | \
grep '^[<>]'
```